# Fill missing values from another row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have PySpark data frame. I need to fill my ID's based on code column
[image]

How can I replace NaN's with matching values from other rows?
Can we use coalesce?

Comment: please make your dataframe readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it. Note that order is not preserved because your original dataframe has no ordering defined.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2 = df.withColumn('ID', F.first('ID', True).over(Window.partitionBy('Code')))

df2.show()
+---+----+
| ID|Code|
+---+----+
|  7|  AZ|
|  7|  AZ|
|  3|  EV|
|  3|  EV|
|  8|  FW|
|  5|  CX|
|  5|  CX|
|  5|  CX|
|  9|  BY|
|  2|  GU|
|  1|  DW|
+---+----+
```

If you want to keep the original ordering, you can do one more step of assigning an index:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('index', F.monotonically_increasing_id()).withColumn('ID', F.first('ID', True).over(Window.partitionBy('Code'))).orderBy('index').drop('index')

df2.show()
+---+----+
| ID|Code|
+---+----+
|  7|  AZ|
|  5|  CX|
|  9|  BY|
|  5|  CX|
|  5|  CX|
|  1|  DW|
|  7|  AZ|
|  3|  EV|
|  8|  FW|
|  3|  EV|
|  2|  GU|
+---+----+
```